# Simplify the complex expression...

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I am asked to simplify the complex expression $$\frac{1}{2}(|{e^{i{\theta}}-1}^2|+|{e^{i{\theta}}+1}|)$$

I have gotten to $$\frac{1}{2}((2-2cos\theta)+(2+2cos\theta))$$ 
 1. Do I expand to get $$\frac{1}{2}(4)$$ OR
 2. Do I factor out the 2 and get $$\frac{1}{2}(2(1-cos\theta)+2(1+cos\theta))$$

Is this answer complete?
Additional question: How would the method change if the argument was negative? i.e. if it was $$\frac{1}{2}(|{e^{-i{\theta}}-1}^2|+|{e^{-i{\theta}}+1}|)$$

Comment: What is $\operatorname{mod}$ in this context?

Comment: It is meant to be Modulus, like the absolute value... I wasnt sure how else to do it. It should be around both terms.

Comment: Do you mean $\lvert e^{i\theta}-1\rvert$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Same for the +1 term.

Comment: Then why don't you just type `|e^{i\theta}-1|`?

Comment: I didnt know it would let me

Comment: Actually, it wont let me. I typed them in and it wont format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complet answer is $2$. That follows from both of your approaches. That is$$(\forall\theta\in\mathbb R):\lvert e^{i\theta}-1\rvert^2+\lvert e^{-i\theta}-1\rvert^2=2.$$Note that this is for *all* real numbers $\theta$. Therefore, it makes no sense to ask what happens if we deal with $-\theta$ instead of $\theta$.

Comment: I have a different question that is exactly the same as this but the argument is negative (like I added toward the bottom of the question) so that is why I was asking. Are you saying that the answer will be the same for both?

Comment: If you prove something for an arbitrary $\theta\in\mathbb R$, you shall have proved it both for positive and for negative real numbers.

Comment: Is this because of the modulus in this question? I don't quite get what you mean sorry. I am doing past exam papers so I have no answers to refer to either.

Comment: I cannot help you here, since I don't understand where your doubt is.

Comment: Is it a different answer for a negative argument or is it the same if everything else in the question is the same?

Comment: I proved it for **every** real argument and therefore **in particular** I proved for negative arguments!

Comment: Okay, thank you.